# How do I display a pdf inside an iframe showing all pdf pages?

Tags: html, pdf, iframe

I've been working on having multiple pdf documents inside a single html page using iFrames. I figured how to insert pdfs inside iFrames but I've been curious if it's possible to add a pdf to an iFrame while showing all the pdf pages; that is, the iframe should display all the pdf content without a vertical scroll bar.

Thanks, Y_Y

Comment: do you mean vertical scroll bar?

Comment: Yes., I meant vertical scroll bar (I just edited my question :p)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<iframe src="mydoc.pdf" width="100%" height="800px"></iframe>
```

I don't think you can show all pages, unless you make the height property large enough to show all pages. You would have to make the height big enough (proportionally) to show all pages based on the width of the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

**IFRAME**

```
<iframe id="fred" style="border:1px solid #666CCC" title="PDF in an i-Frame" src="PDFData.pdf" frameborder="1" scrolling="auto" height="1100" width="850" ></iframe>
```

**Object**

```
<object data="your_url_to_pdf" type="application/pdf">
  <embed src="your_url_to_pdf" type="application/pdf" />
</object>
```